# Would there be any economic consequences if the UK were to leave the ECHR?

Tags: united-kingdom, echr

Before Brexit, leaving the ECHR (European Convention on Human Rights) would've presumably been risky as it could've jeopardized the UK's EU membership, thus costing a significant amount of money to the economy. But now that the UK is out of the EU... are any economic downsides expected if they decide to leave the ECHR? Perhaps the EU threatened to sanction them if they do? Or some economic treaty is dependent on them being ECHR members?

Comment: If leaving the ECHR(European Convention on Human Rights) would be a major issue for EU membership it is likely going to have impacts in other areas. As to the questions yes it would have an impact if they decided to do sanctions but the better question is what would leaving mean in regards to existing treaties and deals.

Comment: Well, Russia left. But no other country, IIRC, so it's hard to have an objective example of a country that wasn't a pariah (EU-wise) which did that.

Comment: @Fizz right but that happened when they were already heavily sanctioned so cause and effect are hard to figure out

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely correct, Greece also left for 5 years while it was a dicatorship https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2022/06/15/what-is-the-european-court-of-human-rights#:~:text=Have%20any%20states%20ever%20left,into%20conflict%20with%20the%20organisation. But again it would be hard to separate any measures EU countries took against Greece back then from that backdrop.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open; the questions asked are quite clear and definite - if UK leaves the ECHR would their trade with any EU country suffer due to any possible economic sanctions or if some economic treaties require them to be a member of ECHR?  These can be answered factually.

Comment: What does UK want to achieve w leaving ECHR?  Mostly crackdown on illegal immigration?  Or other things?  To take an example, making life really difficult for unions would likely engender more backlash and reputational costs than being harsh on immigrants.  The EU already has internal tensions re illegal immigration so achieving unity on difficult measures to push on the UK on that subject may not happen.  Seems like asking to predict future here.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the illegal immigration debacle seems like the most important reason by far. The UK needs *drastic* measures to stop the boat arrivals (such ad mass deportations to Rwanda) and the ECHR is the only hurdle. The question is whether the EU threaten the UK with anything if they do end up leaving, it’s not a prediction contest.

Comment: @JonathanReez The UK government could stop the boat arrivals within a week while fully respecting human rights, by providing legal channels for refugees to enter the UK and claim asylum.

Comment: @MikeScott anyone arriving to the UK from France is *not* a genuine refugee because they're already located in a perfectly safe nation. As soon as they refuse to stay in France they become illegal economic immigrants. If you're escaping an unsafe environment, you don't get to pick and choose where you end up staying. If the EU says you must stay in rural Bulgaria, then that's where you must stay, no questions asked. Anyone who dares to question what they're being generously given must be deported immediately.

Comment: @JonathanReez The Geneva Convention on Refugees contains no such stipulation — refugees are not required to stop and claim asylum in the first safe country they reach, and do not cease to be refugees at that point.

Comment: @MikeScott Yes, that's why the UK would be wise to leave said convention along with the ECHR. They're both outdated and are too kind to economic immigrants.

Comment: @MikeScott That solution... doesn't make any sense if the UK govt doesn't want said refugees/immigrants in the first place.

Comment: @MikeScott:j well, so the solution [in this line of thinking] is for the UK to also exit that treaty. What could the economic consequences be? After all, countries like India or Pakistan are not signatories, IIRC. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Refugee_Convention_Signatories.svg (Or the Saudis, as it turns out. Everybody still buys their oil.)

Comment: BTW, this question is pretty misguided with respect to refugees. Short of overturning or shooting their boats, which the ECHR did explicitly disapprove of, other forms of [land based] pushbacks did get their nod in the past couple of years. There was no case just about pushing boats, so that's somewhat unsettled.

Comment: Also, the ECHR doesn't stop the UK from putting asylum seekers on a small island, like Greece does (on more than one tiny island, IIRC). That would certainly decrease the attraction a lot, just ask all those guys stuck on those Greek islands. It's mostly a red herring the ECHR prevents the UK from taking much nastier measures.

Comment: Actually, I haven't quite kept up with the islands part. Apparently the EU funded the CCACs https://www.refugeesinternational.org/reports/2022/9/20/one-year-since-greece-opened-new-prison-like-refugee-camps-ngos-call-for-a-more-humane-approach for 260 million euros."the average distance from the closest towns is 14 kilometers, with no access to regular, adequate and affordable transport services." and supposedly "with 24/7 CCTV and barbed-wire fences". ECHR-approved, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

It would break the Good Friday Agreement, which specifies “The British Government will complete incorporation into Northern Ireland law of the European Convention on Human Rights (ECHR), with direct access to the courts, and remedies for breach of the Convention”. And it wouldn’t be possible to apply the ECHR to Northern Ireland only, because the ECHR itself requires that it be applied throughout your jurisdiction. Breaking the Good Friday Agreement would have very serious implications for trade relations with both the EU and the US.

Comment: I imagine people in Northern Ireland only care about the ECHR in the context of their own rights and privileges. Very few would object to denying such rights to foreigners. But +1, it's a good point.

Comment: @JonathanReez I think you’ll find that the Irish government, which is a party to the Good Friday Agreement, is very concerned indeed about rights for foreigners (i.e. Irish citizens) in Northern Ireland.

Comment: I'm of course referring to the rights of citizens of countries other than UK and Ireland. Very, very few Irish/Northern Irish citizens would care if the rights of Syrian nationals would be protected.

Comment: @JonathanReez Are you talking about rights of foreigners in their respective home countries or in Northern Ireland? I would agree that few (Northern) Irish citizen care to much about the rights of for example  Syrian nationals in Syria. Syrian nationals who are currently in (Northern) Ireland for whatever reason however would be very different though.

Comment: @quarague I’m talking about the rights of Syrians in Ireland. The Good Friday agreement wasn’t written for their benefit and the Irish don’t particularly care about their rights.

Comment: @JonathanReez What you say is irrelevant, because there’s no binding international human rights framework with protections enforceable by a court independent of any government that could be used to replace the protections of the ECHR while only protecting the rights of Irish and UK citizens.

Comment: @JonathanReez: I knew this bit, but I suppose one can quibble that the GFA is not technically an economic treaty. Although peace usually has economic benefits...