Why did the UK Parliament not close all legal routes for appeal when passing the Safety of Rwanda act?
The Safety of Rwanda is quite broad but as per the opinion of legal experts it still leaves some routes for appeal:

Section 4(4) goes on to provide for very limited circumstances in
which a court can grant an interim remedy to prevent or delay
someone’s removal to Rwanda. Such an interim remedy can be granted
“only if the court or tribunal is satisfied that the person would,
before the review or appeal is determined, face a real, imminent and
foreseeable risk of serious and irreversible harm” if removed to
Rwanda. (Incidentally this is similar to the test for interim measures
applied by the ECtHR.)
These grounds of challenge are obviously designed to be as narrow as
possible. However there is no doubt that such challenges will be
brought, possibly in large numbers. Whether any claim succeeds will
obviously depend on the strength of the evidence about a person’s
individual circumstances and the risk they might face if removed.
The other possible route of challenge is to the ECtHR in Strasbourg.
Again the argument would be that the Act, or a particular decision
under it, breaches a claimant’s ECHR rights. A claimant would be
expected to bring such a claim only once any claims in the domestic
courts have failed. The ECtHR will not be bound by the UK legislation
or by the presumption that Rwanda is “safe”. It will conduct its own
assessment on the basis of the evidence before it.

When passing the Act, why didn't Parliament close all routes for appeal and make it completely impossible for any court to intervene in any manner whatsoever into the deportations? There has been a lot of debate in Parliament over this Act so I expect the answer to exist in one of the public debate transcripts.
I’d expect them to pass a law saying something like “no domestic or international court may delay or stop a deportation to Rwanda” but the actual version is quite a bit weaker.

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/87137/how-does-legislation-tell-judges-to-ignore-a-range-of-human-rights-safeguards/87138#87138

The other possible route of challenge through the ECtHR is discussed in Britain within a broader context. In general, they want to be able to disregard the ECtHR if it suites them. It may not be a viable route.

As a general principle, I strongly doubt that any law that has some version of 'no court can ever challenge this' will go through. Any decent supreme court will strike down the law just because of that phrase.

@quarague The UK supreme court can't strike down primary legislation. The most it can do is inform parliament that the law is incompatible with the Human Rights Act

@Caleth Yes, but so-called 'ouster clauses' are quite controversial. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(Jackson)v_Attorney_General#Significance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R(Privacy_International)_v_Investigatory_Powers_Tribunal

The Government's position is that:

The bill will allow Parliament to confirm that it considers it has sufficient material before it to judge that Rwanda is in general safe and that this finding should not be disturbed by the courts.
It is not, however, possible for Parliament reasonably to conclude that Rwanda will always be safe for every potential individual liable to removal at any point in the future, irrespective of their specific personal circumstances. For that reason, the bill does allow for an exceptionally narrow route to individual challenge to ensure that the courts will interpret the relevant provisions in accordance with the will of Parliament. Not to do so would mean ministers accepting that those unfit to fly, for example those in the late stages of pregnancy, or sufferers of very rare medical conditions that could not be cared for in Rwanda, could be removed with no right to judicial scrutiny.
In any case, completely blocking any court challenges would be a breach of international law and alien to the UK’s constitutional tradition of liberty and justice, where even in wartime the UK has maintained access to the courts in order that individuals can uphold their rights and freedoms. Furthermore, such a wider ouster clause would have to confront unorthodox obiter dictum made in cases such as Jackson v Attorney-General [2005] UKHL 56 and Privacy International [2019] UKSC 22.
The bill limits unnecessary challenges whilst maintaining the principle of access to the courts where an individual may be at a real risk of serious and irreversible harm. Taken as a whole, the limited availability of domestic remedies maintains the constitutional balance between Parliament being able to legislate as it sees necessary, and the powers of our Courts to hold the government to account.

I'm not aware of any debate or amendment seeking to "close all routes for appeal and make it completely impossible for any court to intervene in any manner whatsoever into the deportations".

For example, the legacy of the Rawandan genocide of 1994 almost certainly means that some native Rawandan citizens would be in great danger if they were deported there.

@JohnDallman sure but that might be the only way to prevent judges from interfering into the process. I guess we’ll find out soon enough, once the first flights to Rwanda take off (or don’t take off).

@JohnDallman In October 2023, the day after the Government argued in the Supreme Court that Rwanda is a safe country, the Home Office granted refugee status to a husband and wife fleeing political persecution in Rwanda. Later in the month, another Rwandan was granted refugee status for the same reason. Perhaps the UK will grant Rwandans refugee status while sending non-Rwandans to Rwanda.

@Lag: Yup, the whole policy is going to be ineffective, expensive and inhumane. I didn't want to editorialize in the same comment as reminding people about the genocide.

It's safe unless it's not safe. Makes sense.

@JohnDallman an equivalent policy worked out great for Australia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Sovereign_Borders

@JonathanReez The situations are somewhat different. The distance between France and Britain is smaller and France is not comparable to Indonesia. Britain has not yet sent a single person to Rwanda. Asylum seekers might hope to cross the channel and stay in Britain undetected for example. Surely detention works, but you also lose a bit of humanity along the way, so a clever compromise is maybe better. What happened to the refugees that arrived in Australia? What happened to those that didn't dare going there anymore?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution those who fail to cross into Australia have to stay in Indonesia or Malaysia which aren’t the safest places for a refugee. Those who will fail to cross into the UK will… stay in France which is as safe as it gets. Hence no harm no foul.

@JonathanReez Nobody knows what will happen in the future. Maybe France in turn will do something or these people will still cross the channel. And what happened to people once their cases are processed and if potentially they are in Rwanda? Doesn't make them Rwandanians. I think the idea is clear but it's not clear if it succeeds and there is a price tag included. Just saying it was successful somewhere else cuts the story short a bit.
